# JDBC Prepared Statement . setDate(....) doesn't save the time, just the date.. How can I save the time as well?

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

I have the following Query :

```
INSERT INTO users (user_id, date_created) VALUES (?,?)
```

I have the following prepared statement

```
PreparedStatement insertUser = dbConnection.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

insertUser.setInt(1, 7);
java.util.Date now = new java.util.Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
insertUser.setDate(2, new java.sql.Date((new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())).getTime()));
insertUser.executeUpdate();
```

If I check the database, I find that it is inserting only today's date not the time though, so it would be : `2011-07-29 00:00:00`

What should I put in the `setDate()` to get the time as well?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Instead of **Date** you should use a [**Timestamp**](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) and the **setTimestamp** method.

pratically you have to do something like that:

```
private static java.sql.Timestamp getCurrentTimeStamp() {
    java.util.Date today = new java.util.Date();
    return new java.sql.Timestamp(today.getTime());
}
```

....

```
preparedStatement.setTimestamp(4,getCurrentTimeStamp());
```

Answer (score 6):

The Java type `java.sql.Date` will be normalized to represent only a `SQL DATE` and not an instant of Time. From the API documentation:

> To conform with the definition of SQL DATE, the millisecond values wrapped by a java.sql.Date instance must be 'normalized' by setting the hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds to zero in the particular time zone with which the instance is associated.

The normalization explains why you are seeing `00:00:00` as the time.

If you want to retain the time information, consider using the [Timestamp](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) class that can represent both a Date and a Time.

Obviously, you should also use the corresponding SQL types to define your table structure; if you want to store timestamps in the database, use the SQL type preferred by your database. While some databases and their JDBC drivers might allow you to store timestamps in `DATE` columns, it is advisable to use the equivalent of the `SQL TIMESTAMP` type if it is available.

Answer (score 0):

On SQLServerDatabase side define column as SMALLDATETIME and on java side use

```
Timestamp sqlDate = new Timestamp( System.currentTimeMillis() );
preparedStmt.setTimestamp( ++startIndex, sqlDate );
```

On SQLServerDatabase side don't specify column type as Timestamp else you will get the following exception.

Cannot insert an explicit value into a timestamp column. Use INSERT with a column list to exclude the timestamp column, or insert a DEFAULT into the timestamp column

Comment: I used a Timestamp mysql data type for the column and it worked just fine with no exceptions.