# How to refactor my date/time to allow for setting dates for my users based on their zone?

Tags: java, spring, datetime, spring-mvc, timezone

My code currently uses java dates.

Mysql has column datetime.

I want to allow users to set their timezones, and then in my application I will convert the dates to reflect their timezones.

I am using Spring mvc.

How can I do this?

Comment: Reference prior question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6874146/jdbc-prepared-statement-setdate-doesnt-save-the-time-just-the-date-h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Datetime` type in MySQL does not have timezone associated with it. Instead, by default Connector/J (the MySQL JDBC Driver) gets the date using the **server timezone**. There was a setting for changing that, but I don't know if it is documented, I had to look through the source to see how it works.

I could save the user's timezone it a different column as `VARCHAR`, and use that when creating the date objects. If you don't want to change all your data, you can populate the `time_zone` column with the server default timezone, and then gradually change the timezones for users. Using the following code you can get the UTC Timestamp. The Calendar/Date objects are quite a mess, an you would be better using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/).

```
ResultSet rs = null;

Date date = rs.getDate("date");

TimeZone userTimeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(rs.getString("time_zone"));

Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(userTimeZone);
c.set(1900 + date.getYear(), date.getMonth(),
    date.getDate(), date.getHours(), 
    date.getMinutes(), date.getSeconds());

//what you are actually interested in
long utcTimestamp = c.getTimeInMillis();
```

Answer (score 1):

The common strategy is to store date and time information in the database using UTC (+0) and then convert to/from the users time zone preference in the GUI layer.

Comment: if my dates are already in a particular timezone, I can just as easily adjust no?

Comment: One of the best features of UTC is that you can avoid the mess that is daylight saving time. If you want to have a time zone aware application I would definitely switch to use UTC in both data and service layers.

Comment: @erikxiv That would be best indeed, but on existing systems such data migration might be hard to pull of some times.

Comment: @KirilRaychev Very true, but on the other hand I've seen to many nasty bugs caused by ad hoc time zone handling not to give fair warning.

Comment: @KirilRaychev well my applications not live yet so I can still do it.  do I still use datetime in mysql?

Comment: @Blankman Yup. the DATETIME type does not contain any time zone information so you as the designer must define which time zone the values in the database should be interpreted as.

Comment: @Blankman If its still not live, then you should definitely use UTC Timestamps for you data storage. See `TIMESTAMP` type in MySQL - it uses UTC Timestamps internally (only seconds precision), and returns a date for the server timezone. See [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html)