# java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in date in query expression

Tags: jsp, ms-access, jdbc

Can Someone help me to solve the error. I am getting error when I pass the date `String ex:"01-JAN-2015"` as Parameter in `setString` ?

> javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException:
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in date in
>   query expression '(Event_Dairy) between #Pa_RaM000# and #Pa_RaM001#'.

```
    String url="jdbc:odbc:kaso";
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");  
    Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection(url);       
    PreparedStatement ppdsmt=conn.prepareStatement("select * from Event_Dairy where(Event_Dairy) between #?# and #?#");
    ppdsmt.setString(1,sdate); 
    ppdsmt.setString(2,edate); 
    ResultSet rs=ppdsmt.executeQuery();
    if(!rs.next())
    {
        out.println("NO RECORDS FOUND");
    }
    else
    {%>
        <table border="2">           
         <tr>
             <td>Event Date</td>
             <td>Subject</td>
             <td>Subject Heading</td>
        </tr>
        <%
        do
        {
            eventDate=rs.getString("Event_Dairy");  
            System.out.println("Event Date"+eventDate);
            Subject=rs.getString("Subject");
            Subject_Heading=rs.getString("Subject_Heading"); 
         %>
          <tr>
                <td><%=eventDate%></td>
                <td><%=Subject%></td>
                <td><%=Subject_Heading%></td>
          </tr>
        <%
        }while(rs.next());
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `java.sql.Date` (or `java.sql.Timestamp`) instead of `String`. See [Using setDate in PreparedStatement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18614836/using-setdate-in-preparedstatement)

And no `#` characters around the `?` placeholders in the query.