# Why statement works but not prepared satement in java, jdbc, oracle?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am trying to write a query and get results from oracle db using java and jdbc. My problem is the same query works if I try with statement, but the same query does not work if I use preparedStatement.
Statement Code: (Here I get real count value)

```
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
String sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) CNT FROM DB.TABLE WHERE DAY = TO_DATE('" + sqlDate + "','YYYY-MM-DD')";
rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
```

PreparedStatement Code: (Here I get count value zero)

```
Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(someJava.Util.Date.getTime());// = 2015-09-24
sqlString = "SELECT COUNT(*) CNT FROM DB.TABLE WHERE DAY = TO_DATE(?,'YYYY-MM-DD')";
pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sqlString);                                        
pstmt.setDate(1, sqlDate);          
rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
```

When I sysout my sqlDate prints like: 2015-09-24.

I have same problem with some other queries.
Can anyone know whats wrong here?

Comment: why are you assigning `sqlString` *after* executing your query?

Comment: I am not assigning it, I just wanted to show you what is my sqlString value. I

Comment: @sstan edited my question, thanks

Comment: Because you should **just use a `java.sql.Date`**! What do you think [`PreparedStatement.setDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setDate(int,%20java.sql.Date)) is for??

Comment: @BoristheSpider I can't understand what you are saying, can you pls explain

Comment: Is your date a String? Then you need something like:  ps.setDate(1, java.sql.Date.valueOf("2013-09-04"); Alternatively, your string looks  to be in right format, so you could also use pstmt.setString(1, sqlDate);

Comment: Convert the String to Date first. Something like pstmt.setDate(1, new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(sqlDate));

Comment: Boris means you can get rid of the TO_DATE in your sql string since you're passing in the date as a Date object, you only need TO_DATE if you're passing in a string.

Comment: @DV88 that is not string, if I try like you said, i get the error: The method setString(int, String) in the type PreparedStatement is not applicable for the arguments (int, Date)

Comment: OK, then go with either using the sql.Date. Overview here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18614836/using-setdate-in-preparedstatement

Comment: @NathanHughes Now I understand, Thank you so much. But I don't know why the same thing TO_DATE() works for so many queries I already wrote.  Thanks to BoristheSpider

Comment: @TheGuest because when you do a concatenated query, all variables are converted to `String`, your `TO_DATE` function then turns it back into a `DATE` on the database side. When you use a `PreparedStatement` you pass **typed** data - i.e. you pass your `sqlDate` as a `DATE` and so you no longer need to convert. Win win I say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`TO_DATE`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php) function converts a string to a date given a certain format. So the parameter passed to the prepared statement should be the `String` to be converted by the Oracle function:

```
pstmt.setString(1, sqlDate.toString());
```

Or you can change the query so that the parameter is the date itself and pass the `java.sql.Date` object to the prepared statement:

```
sqlString = "SELECT COUNT(*) CNT FROM DB.TABLE WHERE DAY = ?";
pstmt.setDate(1, sqlDate());
```

Note that, for the normal statement query:

```
String sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) CNT FROM DB.TABLE WHERE DAY = TO_DATE('" + sqlDate + "','YYYY-MM-DD')";
```

the String concatenation will append the string representation of the object, i.e. it is equivalent to:

```
String sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) CNT FROM DB.TABLE WHERE DAY = TO_DATE('" + sqlDate.toString() + "','YYYY-MM-DD')";
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. my sqlDate is not a String, it is of type java.sql.Date and DAY also date

Comment: @TheGuest `sqlDate.toString()` will get the string representation which is the one you're getting in the sysout. See the second solution which is much better.