# Insert date from JDateChooser into Oracle DB

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdatechooser

I've been trying to use JDateChooser to insert a date into my Oracle db but I keep getting this error:

> SQL Error: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string.

Here is my code.

```
        private void addActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    try{
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String d = sdf.format(tdate.getDate());
        System.out.println(d);

    String sql ="INSERT INTO TRACK(TRACKID,TRACKNAME,TRACKDESC,TRACKDATE)VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
        ps=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1,tid.getText());
        ps.setString(2,tname.getText());
        ps.setString(3,td.getText());
        ps.setString(4,d);
        ps.execute();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Added");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `setDate` instead of `setString` for the fourth argument.

```
ps.setDate(4, new java.sql.Date(tdate.getDate().getTime());
```

More info about setting dates 
[Using setDate in PreparedStatement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18614836/using-setdate-in-preparedstatement)

Comment: Thanks heaps! I used ps.setDate(4, new java.sql.Date(tdate.getDate().getTime()));

Comment: I didn't know tDate class. I have updated the answer. Be so kind to accept it.