# How to filter data by date (obtained from a JCalendar) using MySQL

Tags: java

I'm having a hard time trying to filter data by date

MySQL Query

```
public DefaultTableModel getData1(Date start,Date end){
.......
 String sql = "SELECT * FROM torch.new_table WHERE pro_date between '"+start+"' and '"+end+"'";
.....
}
```

Code for get date from a JCalendar

```
DefaultTableModel dm = new Products().getData1(sDate.getDate(), eDate.getDate());
```

Complete code is Here: http://postimg.org/image/4zycbtj4n/

Comment: Use a PreparedStatement http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18614836/using-setdate-in-preparedstatement

Comment: where is the part executing the statements ?

Comment: Complete code is here:    http://postimg.org/image/4zycbtj4n/

Comment: @MuhammadKashifSaeed I've answered your question. Try it and please, mark it as accepted if it helps you. Also, please, edit your question and include your code properly instead of linking images.

Comment: Sorry i'm beginner so i can't understand what u say..... RubioRic                         just simply give me code with example.

Answer (score 1):

Use the wildcard '?' when you are defining the query.

Replace each wildcard using `setDate` and a new `java.sql.Date`.

```
...

String sql = "SELECT * FROM torch.new_table WHERE pro_date between ? and ?";

PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);

ps.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(start.getTime());
ps.setDate(2, new java.sql.Date(end.getTime());

ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
...
```

If you obtain a String from a `JDateChooser`, you can use

```
ps.setDate(1, java.sql.Date.valueOf(start));
ps.setDate(2, java.sql.Date.valueOf(end));
```

More possibilities here [Using setDate in PreparedStatement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18614836/using-setdate-in-preparedstatement)

Comment: in jdateChooser can't convert string to long plz help

Comment: @MuhammadKashifSaeed I think that you are using there java.util.Date instead of java.sql.Date. Also, I got a typo. Try removing "new" [Updated my answer again]

Answer (score 0):

Part of code to filter data by date (Obtained from a jCalender) using MySQL

Thanks for help @RubioRic

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

//dateT and dateE type jDatechooser

```
    String get = sdf.format(dateT.getDate());

    String get1 = sdf.format(dateE.getDate());
```

// Query to select get data from database

```
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM date WHERE DATE(Date) >=   ?  && DATE(Date)  <= ?";

    try{

        Connection conn = dataB.mySqlCon();

        PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

       st.setString(1, get);
       st.setString(2, get1);

        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
```