# How to convert sql date to java

Tags: java, sql, date

SO i have a table in my database, date declared as date. and now i'm coding in java and i need the DATE to be inputted by the user and store it in my database. how does it work? i mean to convert date in to what? thank you!!

for now this is my code

```
        java.util.Date utilDate = new java.util.Date();
        java.sql.Date sqldate = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());
        System.out.print("更新日: ");
        String 更新日 = input.nextLine();
```

Comment: What version of SQL are you using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, etc.) ?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/18615191/2310289

Comment: Search Stack Overflow before posting. This has been handled many many times already.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL SERVER, the following code will convert your date to SQL Server format.

```
java.util.Date utilDate = new java.util.Date(); //date that needs conversion
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime()); //converts to SQL date format
```