# java.sql.BatchUpdateException: The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Tags: java, sql-server, csv, datetime, jdbc

I am trying to do batch insert to SQL Server where I am getting the column values from a `csv` file.

This is how am handling each row of the `csv` file, but I am getting either

> nvarchar cannot converted to numeric

- or  -

> dateTime exception

---

The code:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            Object val = columnVal[i];
            if (StringUtils.isEmptyOrWhitespaceOnly(val.toString())) {
                System.out.println(val);
                ps.setObject(i + 1, null);
            } else {
                System.out.println(val);
                ps.setObject(i + 1, val);
            }

        }
```

Comment: am trying to write a generic insert since i don't know what kind of value is coming from csv file i.e., why i used object array to get values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the SQL Server data type is `DATETIME`, `DATETIME2`, `DATE` etc, use a one of the following data types when setting the object's value:

- `java.sql.date`: you only need a date part
- `java.sql.timestamp`: you need date + time part
- `java.time` classes for Java 1.8+ and you are using a JDBC driver compliant with JDBC 4.2 or later; e.g. `java.time.LocalDateTime`.

You can gain more insights from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18614836/243373) on Stack Overflow.

---

**Edit:**

> I am trying to write a generic insert since I don't know what kind of value is coming from `csv` file i.e., why I used object array to get values

In that case you should be asking that the CSV use date/datetime values that are formatted in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. SQL Server cannot convert any of the permutations of datetime formats. That would be impossible especially since datetime formats in the USA are `mm/dd/yyyy` and those in most other countries typically `dd/mm/yyyy`.

You could get away with setting an explicit date format using [T-SQL SET DATEFORMAT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx), but you would need to know what the format is up front and SQL Server would have to support that format as well.

---

**Edit 2:**

> Actually i tried with date like dd-mm-yyyy format am able to batch insert .am facing problem when i tried the datetime format as dd-mm-yyyy hh.mm.ss . is there any way to handle this

For that first format, it could easily break if the locale changes... it could then interpret as `mm-dd-yyyy` just as easily.

Remember my advice: always use *ISO8061* format when serializing datetimes. You need to use `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss[.mmm]` (the T is a literal `T` character) or `YYYYMMDD[ hh:mm:ss[.mmm]]`. See [DATETIME - Supported String Literal Formats for datetime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx#Anchor_1).

Comment: Actually i tried with date like dd-mm-yyyy format am able to batch insert .am facing problem when i tried the datetime   format as dd-mm-yyyy hh.mm.ss . is there any way to handle this