# Cannot format given object as a date

Tags: java, sqlite, netbeans-8

I want to insert a product into table. For that I have a Date field for which I use Date Chooser Combo. and for adding date for that product I wrote the following code,

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO ProductInfo(Name,Price,Date,Image,Category) values(?,?,?,?,?) ";
            pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.execute();

            pst.setString(1, txt_name.getText());
            pst.setString(2, txt_price.getText());

            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
            String addDate = dateFormat.format(txt_AddDate.getDateFormat());
            pst.setString(3, addDate);
```

But this is giving me "Cannot format given object as a date" error. I've tried a lot but can't solve. Anyone help me please?

Comment: Add the complete stacktrace

Comment: Why not just add the date as a `java.sql.Date`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using setDate in PreparedStatement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18614836/using-setdate-in-preparedstatement)

Comment: How about `pst.setDate(3, txt_AddDate.getDateFormat()));` (assuming that `getDateFormat()` doesn't what the name implies but rather returns a date (otherwise `dateFormat.format(txt_AddDate.getDateFormat());` wouldn't compile either).

Comment: It depends of four database but surely the format MM-dd-yyyy is not correct, what database are u using?

Comment: MySQL database @Mikel

Comment: For mysql yyyy-mm-dd must work, you try it? The value of addDate is correct?

Comment: Yes I've tried that too :( @Mikel

Comment: Exactly, what line throws the exception? ("Cannot format given object as a date"), what is the type of txt_AddDate variable?

Answer (score 0):

in

```
pst.setString(3, addDate);
```

you are telling that you want to use a String in a Date property.

you should change it to

```
pst.setDate(3, addDate);
```

And also why not use the date that you have?
why not?

```
pst.setDate(3, txt_AddDate.getDateFormat());
```

If this don't work because a format or simple because it doesn't return a date and you still want to use the SimpleDateFormat you could use something like:

```
pst.setDate(3, java.sql.Date.valueOf(addDate));
```