# Converting DateFormat into Date

Tags: java, sql, date

I have this code. Datum in games class is DateFormat, and it need to be DateFormat, but in sql I need set Date. How can I convert this DateFormat in Date in this line of code?

```
    try{

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost/internacionalizacija?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8", "root", "");

        String sql = "INSERT INTO utakmice(tim1, tim2, datum) VALUES(?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        //stmt.execute("set names 'utf8'");

        stmt.setString(1, utakmice.getTim1());
        stmt.setString(2, utakmice.getTim2());
        stmt.setDate(3, utakmice.getDatum());
```

Games class:

```
public class Games {
    private String tim1;
    private String tim2;
    private DateFormat datum;

    public Utakmice(String tim1, String tim2, DateFormat datum) {
        this.tim1 = tim1;
        this.tim2 = tim2;
        this.datum = datum;
    }


    public void setTim1(String tim1) {
        this.tim1 = tim1;
    }

    public String getTim1() {
        return tim1;
    }

    public void setTim2(String tim2) {
        this.tim2 = tim2;
    }

    public String getTim2() {
        return tim2;
    }

    public void setDatum(DateFormat datum) {
        this.datum = datum;
    }

    public DateFormat getDatum() {
        return datum;
    }
}
```

And i get date from JFrame, here is code:

```
private void btnSpremiActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

    String tim1 = txtTim1.getText();
    String tim2 = txtTim2.getText();
    DateFormat datum = txtDate.getDateFormat();

    Utakmice utakmice = controll.kreirajUtakmice(tim1, tim2, datum);
    controll.spremiUtakmice(utakmice);
}
```

Comment: You should try to show some input/output example. This is not clear like this. See [ask] to improve your question a bit. Note that [`DateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) is just a pattern used to create a `String` from a `Date` or the opposite. This is not a `Date`, **it doesn't hold any time data**.

Comment: Hint: An object of type `DateFormat` is needed to parse a string to a `Date`-object. So where is your formatted date-string?

Comment: `stmt.setDate(3, new Date());`

Comment: @MenoHochschild can you put some example of that, how it need to be?

Comment: This is hard to understand. Give wider contest, f.e. declarations

Comment: @AxelH I add Games class.

Comment: @AxelH yes, its a DatePicker.. ok, can you give me some simple example how `DateFormat` create `Date` from a `String`. That would help me a lot.

Comment: Since this is a `DatePicker`, you just used the wrong getter to select the `Date` picked in that component, you get its formatter. Unfortunatly, I don't know what component you used (I don't think Swing provide one). Could you show the `import` line where this `DatePicker` class is imported ? (Or give us the framework used). _PS : I will add some example of `DateFormat` usage with the answer, but you can't use this without the `Date` information._

Comment: @AxelH You meen this: `txtDate = new datechooser.beans.DateChooserCombo();` ?! I use `DateChoser.jar`

Comment: @KatjaBilobrk yes, it is exactly what I needed, the jar used. I didn't found documentation but the code should be correct enough. See my answer. You should edit your question to add that information (since this is needed to get the problem ;) ). You can clean the question by removing the methods in the `Games` class (not needed here, replace those line with `//getter and setter`)

Comment: @AxelH ok. I have code without currently errors, but here is new problem. When I run my app I got a message: `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date`

Comment: @KatjaBilobrk my bad, I should have seend the  `PreparedStatement` error sooner... this is a different problem. We usually use `java.util.Date` (well, used), but from SQL, there is a `java.sql.Date`, same "name" but not the same instance. You can see how to create a `java.sql.Date` from a `java.util.Date` on [that thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18614836/using-setdate-in-preparedstatement). Since this is a different problem, I will let my answer untouched, this is to far from the originial question.

Answer (score 1):

You are currently getting a `DateFormat` from a date picker in a `JFrame`. You are just using the wrong getter, you should find a `getDate()`, `getSelectedDate()`, ... that return a `Date`, `LocalDate`, ...

You are using `DateChooserCombo`. Didn't find a javadoc yet but the [source code](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=jdatechooser-master/src/src/datechooser/beans/DateChooserCombo.java) I found show that it provide

```
public Calendar getSelectedDate() { 
    return chooser.getSelectedDate(); 
}
```

It returns a `Calendar`, you can get a `Date` from it using [`Calendar.getTime()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTime())

So instead of have a `DateFormat datum`, update it to `Date datum` and change in your JFrame into

```
Date datum = txtDate.getSelectedDate().getTime(); //Might be null if nothing selected !!
```

And the bean :

```
public class Games{
    private String tim1;
    private String tim2;
    private Date datum; //CHANGED HERE

    //getter and setter
}
```

---

**FYI :**

Currently, the [`DateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) recovered is used to create or stringify a `Date` using [`Date.format(Date)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format(java.util.Date)) and [`Date.parse(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String)).

Here is a simple example using a [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) (a subclass of `DateFormat` allowing to create your own pattern, see the doc for more information)

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
//Convert a String into a Date (matching the pattern above
Date d = sdf.parse("2017-09-20");
//Convert a Date into a String(matching the pattern above
String s = sdf.format(d);
```