# Can you save java.util.Date to DATE in SQL?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, java.util.date

I'm trying to add a date to my SQL database (PostgreSQL), but there seems to be a mismatch, and im suspecting that the date is the culprit. Is it possible to save a `java.util.Date` in a table where the column is set to DATE?

Comment: I figure the database is actually PostgreSQL, and the PGAdmin is the name of the tool you're using to administer the DB, right?

Comment: Yeah, edited it.

Comment: For a DATE column, you likely need `java.sql.Date` instead `java.util.Date`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305973/java-util-date-vs-java-sql-date

Comment: how are you persisting the dates in the database (which framework)?

Comment: in general java.util.date is converted to java.sql.date and this java.sql.Date object type is mapped to a corresponding SQL Date object in the database. Again, in general this should be database vendor agnostic, because they all follow the SQL standard. There are a lot of papers explaining that dates should be saved only in UTF and/or only as BigIntegers (milliseconds) and only converted to real date for displaying purposes (human readable interface). It's a tricky topic (daylight savings, leap seconds, timezones and such).

Comment: Any reason why you are still using the long outdated `Date` class? [The modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) is so much nicer to work with. I recommend you save a modern `java.time.LocalDate` to your date column.

Comment: There are more details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38809770/5772882) and in [the PostgreSQL documentation](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/8-date-time.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a DATE you need to use java.sql.Date not java.util.Date

Comment: Even better a `java.time.LocalDate`. Use the modern date and time API wherever you can.

Comment: @OleV.V. agreed.