# java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string ORA-06512: at line 1

Tags: oracle

I have the following procedure which has hardcoded values for dates. The bill_ent variable is not being used as of now.

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE "CUST_S_PAS_GET_SUMM_BE" (bill_ent in varchar2, v_start_dt in date, v_end_dt in date, pasOutput out CUST_TYPES.cursor_type)
is 
BEGIN open pasOutput for
  select
   pa.bill_ent_name as Billing_Entity
  ,count(pa.encounter_id) as Total_Reg
  from cust_s_pas_activity pa
  where pa.reg_dt_tm between to_date('01-01-2018','dd-mm-yyyy') and to_date('15-01-2018','dd-mm-yyyy')
  group by pa.bill_ent_name
  order by pa.bill_ent_name;
END;
```

This code works fine from the SQL developer. However, when I try it from java, it throws error.

Java Code -

```
String prepSP = "{call CUST_S_PAS_GET_SUMM_BE(?,?,?,?)}";
objDBSqlStmt = objDBConn.prepareCall(prepSP);
objDBSqlStmt.setString(1, be_list);
 objDBSqlStmt.setString(2, sDate);
 objDBSqlStmt.setString(3, eDate);
 objDBSqlStmt.registerOutParameter(4, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
  objDBSqlStmt.executeQuery();
```

The error is:

```
java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
ORA-06512: at line 1

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:439)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:395)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:802)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:436)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:186)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:521)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.doOall8(T4CCallableStatement.java:202)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.executeForRows(T4CCallableStatement.java:1005)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1307)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3449)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3493)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1491)
    at MDJavaProgram.MDDBUtility.getPASSummaryByBE(MDDBUtility.java:11366)
    at MDServLet.MDSPASHome.doGet(MDSPASHome.java:77)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: What are the java types of `be_list` `sDate` and `eDate` variables?

Comment: All of them are String.

Answer (score 0):

use `objDBSqlStmt.setDate(2, java.sql.Date.valueOf(sDate)); and objDBSqlStmt.setDate(3, java.sql.Date.valueOf(eDate));` instead of `objDBSqlStmt.setString(2, sDate);`  you are trying to set string in date.

Comment: Thanks PrashantH.
When I tried   objDBSqlStmt.setDate(2, java.sql.Date.valueOf(sDate));
I get java.lang.IllegalArgumentException.

Comment: sDate/eDate are in "2018-03-15T00:00:00.000+04:00" format. However, if you see the procedure, I have hardcoded dates. At this moment I am not using the sDate/eDate in my procedure.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18615191/5761820 , problem is with the way you are passing date toyour DB , refer link to pass date to your db.

Comment: Thank you Prashant, your suggestion worked and I was able to fix the issue by rewriting my date functionality.