# How do I handle Date type value in DBUtil

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, jdbc, compiler-errors

I am setting values to send queries in my DBUtil file, however two values: start, end - are Date type value in the HTML5 form and in the MySQL DB. How do I handle them in my DBUtil file while setting?

```
myStmt.setInt(1, theBook.getNumber());
myStmt.setInt(2, theBook.getPhone());
myStmt.setDate(3, theBook.getStart());
myStmt.setDate(4, theBook.getEnd());
myStmt.setString(5, theBook.getName());
```

in my Java class, DBUtil and Servlet I imported java.util.Date. If I use (as in exaomle above) myStmt.setDate(X, value) I've gopt an error: *java.util.date cannot be converted into java.sql.date*

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old  `java.util.Date` and `java.sql.Date` classes are now legacy. Supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes. Specifically, `Instant` and `LocalDate`, respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a [`java.sql.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html):

```
myStmt.setDate(3, new java.sql.Date(theBook.getStart().getTime()));
```

Comment: If I use java.sql.Date is it ok if on my Servlet and Java class java.util.Date remains? Is it ok if I import java.sqla.date only for DBUtil and use syntax as you showed me? :)

Comment: @Luke_Nuke If you aren't using `java.util.Date` anywhere else in the same code, sure, you can just import `java.sql.Date`.

Comment: I am importing java.util.Date in my Class.java ServletController.java and ATM also in my DBUtil. So If I do import them (java.util) and i Use syntax: myStmt.setDate(3, new java.sql.Date(theBook.getStart().getTime())); should it be ok? Do I have ti import java.sql.Date for that syntaxt or it is not necessary then? :)

Comment: @Luke_Nuke if you're using the fully qualified class name (`java.sql.Date`), you don't need to import it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Java8+ and Jdbc 4.x you can use [java.time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) with `setObject` instead of `java.util.Date`, where you can also use `LocalDateTime` with your zone Id like so :

```
LocalDateTime startDate = ...
LocalDateTime endDate = ...
myStmt.setObject(4, startDate);
myStmt.setObject(5, endDate);
```

If you stick with Java 7 or less you can see this link :

- [Using setDate in PreparedStatement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18614836/using-setdate-in-preparedstatement)