# Conversion from String to Date Not happening in JAVA

Tags: java, date-parsing, incompatibletypeerror, date

I have  english date coming in string format such as `2011-12-12`.
I need to convert it into Date format so I tried :

```
 String assignDates="2011-12-12";
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd");
    Date dates = df.parse(assignDates);
    cstmt.setDate(2,dates);
```

But i need to set it into **cstmt.setDate(2,dates);** but it is showing me error in this line like this:

> The method setDate(int, java.sql.Date) in the type PreparedStatement
>   is not applicable for the arguments (int, java.util.Date)

[image]

The full code is:

```
public String getConvertedDateToBs(String assignDates) {
        try
        {
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd");
            System.out.println("yo ni chiryo"+assignDates);
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbProperties.getDatabaseUrl());
        System.out.println("chiryoassignDatea");
            CallableStatement cstmt = conn.prepareCall("{? = call PCFN_LIB_ETON(?)}");
            cstmt.registerOutParameter(1,Types.VARCHAR);
            //java.sql.Types.VARBINARY
            Date dates = df.parse(assignDates);
            cstmt.setDate(2,dates);
            cstmt.executeUpdate();
            dateInBs = cstmt.getString(1);

            /*dateInBs = df.format(assignBsDate);*/
            System.out.println(dateInBs);
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
          System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return dateInAd;
    }
```

Comment: your error already explain. `setDate` method need `java.sql.Date` type. But, your date is `java.util.Date` type -> change `cstmt.setDate(2, new java.sql.Date(dates.getTime()))`

Comment: Problem with imports? java.sql.Date or java.util.Date

Comment: First verify the format specifiers are what you really want - [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html); Second consider using the `java.time` API instead ([this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18614836/using-setdate-in-preparedstatement) shows you how); Third, the error message seems pretty obvious, you are using a `java.util.Date` when the method is expecting a `java.sql.Date` - you have the wrong type

Comment: Not what you asked, but you want `yyyy-MM-dd`.  `Y` is different from `y` - it was added to Java to catch out people who don't read Javadocs.

Comment: @MohamedAneesA i have imported import java.util.Date;

Comment: Actually, the simplest thing to do is to import `java.sql.Date` but NOT `java.util.Date`.  Then you can write `Date.valueOf(yourString)` and all your problems will go away.  If you need `java.util.Date` for some other reason (and you _really_ don't, since it's kind of obsolete these days), you can just write `java.sql.Date.valueOf(yourString)` without importing `java.sql.Date`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using at least JDBC version 4.2 (which you probably are), it’s much easier and more straightforward than you think (not tested):

```
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(assignDates);
        cstmt.setObject(2, date);
```

No need for `DateFormat`/`SimpleDateFormat` and no need for `java.util.Date` nor `java.sql.Date`. Which is very good because those classes had design problems, the first in particular are notoriously troublesome. All of these old classes are considered long outdated.

Instead use `LocalDate` from java.time, the modern Java date and time API. The modern API is much nicer to work with.

I am taking advantage of the fact that your string, `2011-12-12`, is in ISO 8601 format, the format that the modern date and time classes parse (and also print) as their default, that is, without any explicit formatter.