# SpringBoot oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-boot, spring-mvc

> 2019-03-01 16:38:44.930  WARN 55052 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
>   o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 932, SQLState:
>   42000
>
> 2019-03-01 16:38:44.930 ERROR 55052 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
>   o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ORA-00932: inconsistent
>   datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER
>
> 2019-03-01 16:38:44.946 ERROR 55052 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
>   o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for
>   servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
>   [Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could
>   not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract
>   ResultSet] with root cause
>
> oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-00932: inconsistent
>   datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER

Query that I want eventually, I guess just not correctly formed using spring CrudRepository:

```
select * from user_usage where Prs_Id=1104438622 and createddate > sysdate -1;
```

desc user_usage

```
Name          Null     Type           
------------- -------- -------------- 
USAGETYPEID   NOT NULL NUMBER(3)      
PRS_ID        NOT NULL NUMBER(18)     
CREATEDID     NOT NULL NUMBER(10)     
CREATEDDATE   NOT NULL DATE           
COMMENTS               VARCHAR2(4000) 
USERAGENTID            NUMBER(10)
```

1)POJO

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="USER_USAGE)
    public class Usage {

        @Column(name="Prs_Id")
        @Id
        private long prsId;

        @Column(name="createddate")
        private Date createddate;
```

2)Repository

```
    public interface UsageRepository extends CrudRepository<Usage, Date>{


        //select * from user_usage where Prs_Id=1104438622 and createddate > sysdate -1; --query that I want eventually 
         @Query("SELECT a FROM Usage a WHERE a.prsId=:prsId and a.createddate>=:createddate-1")
         Usage fetchUsageGreaterThanEqual(@Param("prsId") Long prsId, @Param("createddate") Date createddate);
    }
```

3)Controller :

```
    @Autowired
    UsageRepository usageRepository; 
    static Date myDate;

    @GetMapping("/{prsId}")
     public Usage getUsageByPrsId(@PathVariable Long prsId) {
      return usageRepository.fetchUsageGreaterThanEqual(prsId, myDate);
     }
```

Comment: why are you subtracting 1 from sysdate?

Comment: I tried to replicate with H2 inmemory it is working fine

Comment: @Deadpool, I am trying to fetch data since yesterday so subtracting from current date, any other workaound not much familiar with CRUD methods ?

Comment: @Anil, as its a ORA error, its coming from Oracle due inconsistent datatypes from java layer.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Date`  class is most probably `java.util.Date`

```
static Date myDate;
```

You must convert it to `java.sql.Date` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18615191/4808122)

```
new java.sql.Date(createddate.getTime())
```

to avoid the problem with `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER`

Alternatively you may also use the [`java.time`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31238011/4808122) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32443004/4808122)

Comment: I have replaced from util to sql.Date i.e. "Date myDate=new java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMillis());"                                                                but getting :                                                                                                                    "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [2019-03-03] did not match expected type [java.lang.Integer (n/a)]"                                                                                                                                        If I do sysout it shows as : myDate=2019-03-03