# MySQL select all rows from this year to a specific month from last year

Tags: java, mysql, sql, date, jdbc

I'm creating a system for a school that needs to retrieve data from April of this year to June from last year.

I needed a query that can retrieve from this dates due to their school year always starts from June and end in April.

I tried selecting dates using Where clause.

```
"SELECT * FROM students WHERE year(c_date) = ? AND month(c_date) = ? AND c_occupation = 'Student'"
```

the question marks are use for java language which to prepare a statement using this code

```
pst=conn.prepareStatement(Sql);
            pst.setInt(1, year);
            pst.setInt(2, month);
```

I also tried this method but with this, I need to enter the date again after a year has pass.

```
SELECT users.* FROM users 
WHERE dateadded <= '2019-06-01' 
AND dateadded >= '2018-4-30'
```

I wanted it to automatically based on what today's year is.

So for example today is March 20, 2019.
I should be able to return all the values from this day until June 1, 2018

Comment: Have you tried using the "between" operator? Also, you could try setting the date via PreparedStatement, instead of using int values: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18614836/using-setdate-in-preparedstatement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code can be :

```
LocalDate from = LocalDate.now().minusYears(1); // 2018-04-29
LocalDate to = LocalDate.of(Year.now().getValue(), Month.JUNE, 1); // 2019-06-01

String sql = "SELECT * FROM students WHERE dateadded BETWEEN ? AND ? AND c_occupation = 'Student'";
pst = conn.prepareStatement(Sql);
pst.setObject(1, from);
pst.setObject(2, to);
```

---

- `LocalDate.now().minusYears(1);` return the same day of last year
- `LocalDate.of(Year.now().getValue(), Month.JUNE, 1);` return the 1st June of the current year
- `dateadded BETWEEN ? AND ?` will select all between the `from` and `to` dates
- `pst.setObject(1, from);` if you are using JDBC 4+ you can set a `LocalDate` like so

---

Some references :

- [MySQL: BETWEEN Condition](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/between.php)
- [java.time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your last method can be made to work using this approach

```
SELECT * FROM students 
WHERE dateadded BETWEEN (CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-06-01') - INTERVAL 1 YEAR) AND CURDATE() 
AND c_occupation = 'Student';
```