# Java Insert button with MySQL add to database and table

Tags: java, file

I cant see why it doesn't work. 
Its Java Insert button. Error is in InputStream line. 2 imports added. Stream import java.io.FileInputStream; import java.io.InputStream;

InputStream img = new FileInputStream(new File(ImgPath)); error unreported exception FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared

```
    private void Btn_InsertActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

        if (checkInputs() && ImgPath != null) {
            try {
                Connection con = getConnection();
                PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO products(name,price,add_date,image"
                        + "value(?,?,?,?) ");
                ps.setString(1, "txt_name.getText()");
                ps.setString(2, "txt_price.getText()");
                SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                String addDate = dateFormat.format("txt_AddDate.getDate()");
                ps.setString(3, addDate);

                InputStream img = new FileInputStream(new File(ImgPath));
                ps.setBlob(4, img);
                ps.executeUpdate();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data ");

            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
            }

        }
        else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "One or More Filed Are Empty");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not catch the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the catch block to this :

```
catch (SQLException | FileNotFoundException ex) {
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Yes it helped but there was another error Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date

Comment: Code has no error but when i compile, im adding data to all and push button insert  - Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date
 at java.base/java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:338)
 at java.base/java.text.Format.format(Format.java:158)
 at java_project_1_2.Main_Window.Btn_InsertActionPerformed(Main_Window.java:41... etc

Comment: @TomaszBarański  Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18614836/using-setdate-in-preparedstatement

Comment: @TomaszBarański Please ask only one question at a time and do not ask for further help in the comments.

Comment: I have tried to add it over here not sure if it should be over there but it didn't work same error- 
ps.setString(1, "txt_name.getText()");
ps.setString(2, "txt_price.getText()");
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

                //String addDate = dateFormat.format("txt_AddDate.getDate()");
                //ps.setString(3, addDate);
                
                ps.setDate(3, java.sql.Date.valueOf("txt_AddDate.getDate()"));

Comment: @TomaszBarański Please if you are facing other problem in the code. Raise a new question. I have already answered to the your question.