# How to add date to database from java

Tags: java, date, jdbc, sqlexception

I am having trouble trying to add dates to my database.

This is my code

```
public void AddStudent(String idStudent, String name, String idClass, String dateOfBirth, String sex, String address){

    Connection connect = classConnection.connect;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    String query = "insert into students values(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    try {
        ps = connect.prepareStatement(query);
        ps.setString(1, idStudent);
        ps.setString(2, name);
        ps.setString(3, sex);
        ps.setString(4, dateOfBirth);
        ps.setString(5, address);
        ps.setString(6, idClass);
        ps.execute();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Error: " + e.toString());
    } 
}
```

This is the error

> conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

How do I solve this?

Comment: You're submitting a value that cannot be parsed as a date or time. Show how you're calling this.

Comment: dateOfBirth is a String, but your 4th argument of the table students is not.

Comment: See [Using setDate in prepared statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18614836/using-setdate-in-preparedstatement).

Comment: Please read [Insert & fetch java.time.LocalDate objects to/from an SQL database such as H2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43039614/insert-fetch-java-time-localdate-objects-to-from-an-sql-database-such-as-h2). It shows a superior approach.

Comment: @GeorgeZ. Using `PreparedStatement.setDate()` is the obsolete way. [The answer by Basil Bourque](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38809770/5772882) is very good, though. Also see my link for the modern approach.

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67752047/10819573) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67505173/10819573) to learn how to use `java.time` API with JDBC.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse it fist to date, on the same format as your database format().
For shortcut, you can use setDate from PreparedStatement.