# SQL error or missing database (near ":01": syntax error) in SQLite

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

I'm trying to update a SQLite table with Java. This is the relevant part of the code:

```
    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:test.db");
        c.setAutoCommit(false);
        System.out.println("Opened database successfully");
        stmt = c.createStatement();
        String sql = "INSERT INTO AMBROZIJA (LEVEL,DATE,TIME) " +
                "VALUES ("+koncentracijaAmbrozije+","+date+","+time+");";
        System.out.println(sql);
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        stmt.close();
        c.commit();
        c.close();
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
        System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
        System.exit(0);
    }
    System.out.println("Records created successfully");
```

When I run the code, I get the following output:

```
INSERT INTO AMBROZIJA (LEVEL,DATE,TIME) VALUES (6.5,2020-08-21,18:01:44.087078100);
org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near ":01": syntax error)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

The "near x" in `(near ":01": syntax error)` part is from the minutes part of time so it changes with every execution.

How can I fix this error (I don't know much about SQLite)?

Comment: Date and time values should be enclosed inside single quotes, but it is better to learn to use Prepared statements: https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-java/insert/

Comment: You should look into [prepared statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix your problem columns `time` but the `date` should be passed within quotes and you can add the quotes while concatenating value,

```
date = "'"+ date +"'";
time = "'"+ time +"'";        
String sql = "INSERT INTO AMBROZIJA (LEVEL,DATE,TIME)" +
          " VALUES (" + koncentracijaAmbrozije + "," + date + "," + time+ ");";
```

But it is good practice and always recommended to bind the values instead concatenating it using `prepareStatement` as also suggested in the comment but its little bit more work when you deal with date columns. found a good [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18614836/using-setdate-in-preparedstatement) which you can take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Pass it as string with single quotes, or you can use **strftime()** method like this:

`strftime('%Y-%m-%d','2020-08-21')`

You may take a look at the manual for all valid substitutions
[Date And Time Functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)