# Inserting the exact time into a database

Tags: java, sql-server

When you insert the following into a SQL database:

```
Date now = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
PreparedStatement audit = sqlConn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO [Table](Date) VALUES (?)");
audit.setDate(1, now);
audit.execute();
```

This is the result:

2013-09-06 00:00:00.000

How do I also get the time information inserted into the database?

Edit: The column datatype is DateTime.

Comment: how is your `Date` field defined?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6874146/jdbc-prepared-statement-setdate-doesnt-save-the-time-just-the-date-h).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be confusing:

- The `java.util.Date` class which represents a date *and* a time-of-day in UTC
- The `java.sql.Date` class which represents a date-only, without time-of-day and without time zone.

Actually, java.sql.Date extends java.util.Date so it does in fact inherit a time-of-day but pretends to not have a time-of-day by setting it to `00:00:00.0` in UTC. The class doc tells you ignore the inheritance relationship (it's a hack). Confusing? Yes, these old date-time classes are a mess, poorly designed, confusing, and troublesome.

These old classes were supplanted by the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. Much of the functionality has been back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in ThreeTen-Backport and further adapted to Android in ThreeTenABP.

If your database column is of a type similar to the SQL standard type TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE, then you can use either:

- [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html)
  A moment on the timeline in UTC with a resolution up to nanoseconds.
  `Instant instant = Instant.now();`
- [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html)
  Like an `Instant` but adjusted into a particular time zone.
  `ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) );`

If your JDBC driver complies with JDBC 4.2 spec, you can pass either of these via the `setObject` method on a `PreparedStatement`.

If your driver does not support the direct use of java.time types, fall back to using java.sql types. Find new methods added to the old classes for converting to/from java.time types. You are looking for the [`java.sql.Timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) class in particular for a date-time value, which can convert to/from `Instant`. From a `ZonedDateTime` you can extract an `Instant` for this purpose of conversion.

```
java.sql.Timestamp ts = java.sql.Timestamp.from( instant );
java.sql.Timestamp ts = java.sql.Timestamp.from( zdt.toInstant() );
```

Going the other direction.

```
Instant instant = mySqlTimestamp.toInstant();
```

Answer (score 1):

Some database only store up to the second precision for the date.

SQLserver's [`datetime`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) supports fractional seconds, but it rounds to the nearest 3 milliseconds.

If you need more precision, store your date as a bigint type and pass the `now.getTime()` Java `long` value instead.

Comment: Yes, I am using datetime.

Comment: Actually I am not, this was a copy and paste error I will fix it.

Comment: @DavidTunnell Then I would recommend you look at your schema and the link I posted. What happens if you do a `select Date from [Table]`? How do the dates appear in a console?