# Getting the totalworkingdays dates through passing the dates dynamically

Tags: java, mysql, database, date, jdbc

This is my  MySQL database table structure and attendancedate datatype is Date:

```
attendancedate-------admissionnumber------------attendance
2013-10-03-----------LSTM-0008/2013-2014--------present
2013-10-09-----------LSTM-0008/2013-2014--------present
2013-11-02-----------LSTM-0008/2013-2014--------absent
```

and i want to disaply like that

```
monthname---------totalworkingdays---------present----absent
october-------------- 2--------------------2----------0
November--------------1--------------------0-----------1
```

so am writing the below MySQL query:

```
select monthname(attendencedate) as monthname,
         (select distinct count(*) 
            from lstms_attendence 
           where attendencedate>='2013-10-03'
             and attendencedate<='2013-10-09' 
             and addmissionno='LSTM-0008/2013-2014')as totalworkingdays,
        sum(CASE WHEN attendence = 'present' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as present,
        SUM(CASE WHEN attendence = 'absent' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS absent 
   FROM lstms_attendence 
  WHERE addmissionno='LSTM-0008/2013-2014' GROUP BY monthname(attendencedate);
```

But the query is display like this:

```
monthname---------totalworkingdays---------present----absent
November-----------3-----------------------0------------2
October------------3-----------------------2------------1
```

please give me the exact query and here am passing dates as hardcoded but that dates are passing dynamically through java to that query.

Let me know the how to create dynamically dates and how to pass values to that query.

Comment: Please format the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    MONTHNAME(attendencedate) as the_month,
    COUNT(*) as working_days,
    SUM(IF(attendance='present',1,0)) as is_present,
    SUM(IF(attendance='absent',1,0)) as is_absent
FROM
    lstms_attendence
WHERE
    addmissionno='LSTM-0008/2013-2014'
GROUP BY
    the_month
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't make clear what you're asking. What's wrong with your resultset? Is it the presence of your "november" row?

At any rate, you've got an excessively complex query here, as well as one which will break if you happen to include data from multiple years in it.

Instead of using MONTHNAME(attendancedate), we'll use

```
   DATE_FORMAT(attendancedate, '%Y-%c-01') AS attendancemonth
```

to figure out in which month an attendancedate lies.  This simply turns '2013-11-15' into '2013-11-01', the first day of the month in question. In other words, it truncates (rounds down) the date to the first day of the month.

```
   SELECT admissionnumber,
          DATE_FORMAT(attendancedate, '%Y-%c-01') AS attendancemonth,
          COUNT(*)                                AS working_days,
          SUM(IF(attendance='present',1,0))       AS is_present,
          SUM(IF(attendance='absent',1,0))        AS is_absent
     FROM lstms_attendence
    WHERE attendancedate >= '2013-10-03'
      AND attendancedate < '2013-10-06' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
      AND admissionnumber='LSTM-0008/2013-2014'
 GROUP BY admissionnumber,attendancemonth
```

Here is a sqlfiddle.http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2dfb/7/0

This summarizes by both admissionnumber and month, so you can produce a report that contains multiple admissions if you want that.

It uses `attendancedate < 'last' + INTERVAL 1 DAY` in place of `attendancedate <= 'last'` because that is robust in cases where `attendancedate` contains a timestamp other than midnight.

If you need to pass in your parameters from Java, use a prepared statement. Replace the constants in the SQL query with `?`, and use setTimestamp and setString.  For one example, see [JDBC Prepared Statement . setDate(....) doesn't save the time, just the date.. How can I save the time as well?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6874146/jdbc-prepared-statement-setdate-doesnt-save-the-time-just-the-date-h)