# PreparedStatement sql setDate

Tags: java, sql, date

I have this query :

```
String sql ="select col1,col2,col3 from table where tstamp between '01/01/2014 00:00' and '01/01/2014 23:59'" ;
```

I want to use a `PreparedStatement` to `setDate` like this :

```
String sql = "select col1,col2,col3 from table where tstamp between ? and ? " ;

PreparedStatement p = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
```

`p.setDate(1,..);`

and I don't know how to do it..please help

I tried the new `Date(int,int,int)` constructor but it doesn't set the hours and minutes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JDBC Prepared Statement . setDate(....) doesn't save the time, just the date.. How can I save the time as well?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6874146/jdbc-prepared-statement-setdate-doesnt-save-the-time-just-the-date-h)

Answer (score 1):

JDBC has three temporal types, all in the `java.sql` package:

1. Date, which contains a date without time
2. Time, which contains a time without date
3. Timestamp, which contains a date and a time.

You thus need to use a [Timestamp](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html), and the `setTimestamp()` method of `PreparedStatement`.

To construct a Timestamp instance from a String, use a `SimpleDateFormat` to parse the String into a `java.util.Date` object, then construct the Timestamp by passing the milliseconds obtained from this `java.util.Date` object.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the [Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) object from *java.sql* is different that the [Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) from *java.util*

Then if You use *p.setDate(1,..);* with a *java.util.Date* You will lose the ***time***.
One possible solution could be that You passed as argument a Date from *java.sql*

Answer (score 0):

Use `java.sql.Date`

```
try{
    sql   = "select col1,col2,col3 from table where tstamp between ? and ? ;
    pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    pstmt.setString(1, /**Your Date**/);
    pstmt.setString(2, /**Your Date**/);
    rs    = pstmt.executeQuery();
        . 
        . 
        .
}catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}finally{
    sql = null;
    if(rs != null){
        rs.close();
        rs = null;
    }
    if(pstmt != null){
        pstmt.close();
        pstmt = null;
    }
    if(conn != null){
        conn.close();
        conn = null;
    }
}
```

For [More](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/how-to-insert-timestamp-value-in-preparedstatement/)