# Java date to sql date

Tags: java, sql-date-functions, sqldatetime

How can I store a specific date from java to my database? (Not only the date today, but also some dates that the user wants to specifiy)

```
try {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");       
        Date date = dateFormat.parse(tf.getText());
        String d = dateFormat.format(date); 

        String str = "insert into tableName(tDate) values (?)";
                con = mysqlConnection.dbConnector();
                prs = con.prepareStatement(str);
                prs.setDate(1, // dont know what to put here);

                int rsUpdate = prs.executeUpdate();
                con.close();
                prs.close();
    } catch(ParseException exx) {
                System.err.println(exx);
```

Comment: Use a second table, which is keyed via a foreign key, to the first

Comment: Have a look at this [SO Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6874146/jdbc-prepared-statement-setdate-doesnt-save-the-time-just-the-date-h)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Save the 'date' as String first on the other table?

Comment: Save the date as `java.sql.Date`...(I also assume you mean you want to store a variable list of dates)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Date - Insert into database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081234/java-date-insert-into-database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
prs.setDate( 1, new java.sql.Date( date.getTime() ) );
```

The types `java.sql.Date` and `java.sql.Timestamp` are suppoed to be used to set date and timestamp fields, respectively. Read their documentation for the differences between them and between them and `java.util.Date`.

You usually get a java date (`java.util.Date`) from the user. You convert it to milliseconds since the epoch using `getTime()`, and then convert back to a `java.sql.Date` or `java.sql.Timestamp` as I have shown.

Comment: It inserts a whole bunch of 000's

Comment: @meantro Then you should put in your original question: (a) the definition of the table, and (b) the result of `System.out.println(date)` just before you do the `setDate()` so that we know it contains valid data.

Answer (score 0):

use this it can help

```
  static  java.sql.Timestamp getSqlDate(Date date) {    
        java.util.Date javaDate = date;
        long javaTime = javaDate.getTime();
        java.sql.Timestamp sqlTimestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(javaTime);
        return sqlTimestamp;
 }
```